# How to select range before convert xlsx to pdf using convertapi

Tags: convertapi

Using convertapi, I would like to set range and convert only selected area to pdf. Is this possible?

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
require_once 'vendor/convertapi/convertapi- 
php/lib/ConvertApi/ConvertApi.php';
use \ConvertApi\ConvertApi;
ConvertApi::setApiSecret('secret');
$result = ConvertApi::convert('pdf', [
    'File' => 'output/spreadsheet_2.xlsx',
], 'xlsx'
);
$result->saveFiles('output');
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you can set only `WorksheetName` or `WorksheetIndex` parameters for narrowing down what you want to convert.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a range of sheets, you can only loop on the range, each time converting a separate PDF from one sheet at a time.
No better choice up until now.